# Getting Initials from a name in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm sure there's a more eloquent way:

```
NAMES <- data.frame(ID = "George Washington")
NAMES$ID <- as.character(NAMES$ID)

gsub(" ", "", paste(substr(data.frame(strsplit(NAMES$ID, " "))[[1]], 1, 1), collapse=" "))
```

[1] "GW"

Comment: Use `gsub("[^A-Z]*([A-Z])[^A-Z]*", "\\1", NAMES$ID)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can match one or more characters that are not a upper case letters (`[^A-Z]+`) that follows an upper case letter (using the regex lookaround -`(?<=[A-Z])`) and replace it with a blank (`""`)

```
gsub("(?<=[A-Z])[^A-Z]+", "", NAMES$ID, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "GW"
```

Or without lookaround and using capture groups.  We capture the upper case letter as a group followed by one or more non upper case letters and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`)

```
gsub("([A-Z])[^A-Z]+", "\\1", NAMES$ID)
#[1] "GW"
```

Just to be safe, we can also include the word boundary

```
gsub("(\\b[A-Z])[^A-Z]+", "\\1", NAMES$ID)
```

Comment: When I benchmark mine and your first seem the fastest.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for the comments.  The reason could be that there are multiple functions in your code, which could slow down the process

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it, which also includes a non-english solution (I'm scandinavian myself but think it goes for a lot of different languages.

It's quite easy with English, and gets more involved with other languages.

Basically I added all non-English letters like ÅÆÅ I could find, from a dictionary-file (*.dic) and used that instead of \W and \w. Using the word-boundary special character "\b" messes stuff up, however, so the simple solution is just not to use it. Simply excluding it did not pose a problem with my data but there might the edge cases where it could be a problem so be careful and look at the results.

```
# with english chars it is 'quite' easy, but it can't deal with the last element
name <- c('John Dean', 'PETER Lemon', 'Simon Says', 'Åse Æsel')
searchstring <- '\\W*\\b(\\w)\\w*' # the \\b might not be a good idea, depending on the strings in question
searchstring <- '\\W*(\\w)\\w*'
gsub(searchstring, '\\1', name,perl=T)

# With other languages it gets more involved.
name <- c('John Dean', 'Lille ãder', 'Åse Æsel', 'Henrik d. 9')
notall_wordchars <- '[^A-Za-z0-9_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþ]'
all_wordchars <- '[A-Za-z0-9_ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþ]'
searchstring <- paste0(notall_wordchars, '*',
'(', all_wordchars, ')', all_wordchars, '*')

gsub(searchstring, '\\1', name,perl=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar in **stringr**. Assuming that **name** consists of two words separated by at least one space, you can use the following. Note that the last name is a "team", so initials are not required or done.

```
library(stringr)
    name <- c('John Dean', 'PETER Lemon', 'Simon Says', 'Åse Æsel', "The R Team")
    create_initials <- function(names){
        stringr::str_replace(names, 
                             pattern = "^(\\w{1})(\\w+)\\s(\\w{1})(\\w+)$",
                             replace = "\\1\\3"
        )
    }
    create_initials(name)
#> [1] "JD"         "PL"         "SS"         "ÅÆ"         "The R Team"
```

The key in the replacement is found in [this reference](https://dcgerard.github.io/stat_412_612/lectures/08_strings/08_strings.pdf): "You can use parentheses to control where the alternation occurs. # Parentheses create a numbered group that you can then back reference with \1 for the match in the first parentheses, \2 in the second parentheses, etc."

With respect to the original post

```
NAMES <- data.frame(ID = "George Washington")

NAMES %>% mutate(ID = create_initials(ID))
#>  ID
#> 1 GW
```

`Created on 2021-10-12 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)`